# Can you use character '}' in <Text> and show it on the emulator?

Tags: react-native

This is just a question that popped out of my head can you use character **'}'** in `<Text>` and show it on emulator?

and my first thought is just to do this:

```
  const characterInString = "{"
  ...
return(
    <View>
          { characterInString }
    </View>

    )
```

But could you *only* put a **'}'** in a `<Text>` and show it on emulator and are there other methods?

Simply to put it could you do this `<Text>{</Text>` and show  `<Text>` on the emulator?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, please rephrase your question.

Comment: I meant could you use the character '{' in a <Text> as a string? does that make sense?

Comment: you mean like that <Text>}<Text>?

Comment: Yes, and make it show the character '}' on the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since { is a special character inside a `<Text>`, you cannot just write it like there. There is also no way to escape the character. The easiest way is to write `<Text>{'{'}</Text>`